# Redirects aren't working from com_redirect

Tags: administration, redirect

I'm trying to have one url redirect to a different url, and I'm trying to get Joomla to handle it.

In com_redirect in the Joomla admin, I'll add an entry for one url to be redirected to an second url, but the redirect doesn't happen.

For example:

```
Source URL: http://www.domain/menu?query=param
Destination URL: http://www.domain/destination
Status: Enabled
```

I have my htaccess file setup and url rewriting enabled in the global configuration. What do i need to do to get this redirect working?

Comment: Is the redirect plugin enabled?

Comment: yes, the plugin is enabled. I've also tried trashing all the disabled redirects, but the one that's enabled still won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tested it with Redirect Component but you can not redirect url with GET parameters as they get passed in a different variable in Apache. So your source would be ignored.
You would need to write it in the .htaccess file with extra settings: (not tested)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=param(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/menu [NC]
RewriteRule .* /destination [R=301,L]
```

See for other examples:
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165811/htaccess-rewrite-with-http-host-and-query-string